# Как нарисовать линию с символьным паттерном?

Tags: c++, qt, рисование

Необходимо нарисовать линию со сложным паттерном в виде символа при помощи QPainter. Как в примере ниже.

[image: Пример]

Comment: Эта штука похожа на векторный объект карты. Если это действительно карта, то лучше не рисовать самому с помощью QPainter.

Comment: А так берёте QPainter, он умеет крутиться на определённый угол, перемещаться, рисуете горизонтально все эти треугольнички и кружочки c помощью QPainter, перед этим переместив его в стартовую точку и повернув на нужный угол. QPainter сам всё сделает. Вам только цикл написать надо будет - рисуем три треугольника, кружочек, три треугольника, кружочек, пока не нарисуем все что надо.

Comment: Треугольник рисуется с помощью трёх отрезков, но у вас тут основание широкое, получится 5 точек, три для двух сторон треугольника плюс две для основания. Кружочек рисуется кругом, символ - это просто текст надо нарисовать. Не понимаю в чём проблема, не понятно как отрезки рисуются, или как символ рисуется, или как круг рисуется ?

Comment: Отрезок - `drawLine`, круг - `drawArc`, текст - `drawText`. На листочке можете нарисовать ручкой? Вот так же QPainter можно сказать. Или циклы не знаете в C++ ?  Повернуть систему координат рисования - `rotate`, перенести центр координат рисования  - `translate`. Вот ссылка на документация по [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html)

Comment: @vt-egorov А что Вы подразумеваете под "не рисовать самому"?  А как еще? Я думаю создать атлас растровых символов и рисовать растровые фрагменты. Я так понимаю что необходимо разбить линию на точки, но пока не представляю как эффективно это сделать.

Comment: Если это векторный знак на карте, то у него должна быть метрика, список координат на карте. То есть Вы должны уметь переводить координаты в некоторой геодезической системе координат в некоторую картографическую проекцию, и после этого сопоставлять пиксель карты в зависимости от масштаба отображения карты и параметров экрана координатам точки в проекции. Обычно этим всякие ГИС занимаются. Если у Вас уже все это есть, то тогда наверное можно и просто с помощью QPainter нарисовать. В гис обычно есть средства для создания векторных объектов, можно поручить отрисовку ГИС.

Comment: Ну если только Вы не пишите свою собственную ГИС, тогда всё понятно =)

Comment: @vt-egorov именно так. Морская навигационная ГИС, где некоторые линии, согласно стандарту должны иметь довольно сложный паттерн